# How to Get the Selected value for the select choice element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to get the value of the selected option as,var

```
doma=$('#domain_picker_select').find('option:selected').text();
OR
var doma=$('#domain_picker_select').val();
```

but i am getting the output as undefined, please help me  to get the values for the option been selected for the select choice.

```
<select name="domain_picker_select"ng-options="domain.value as domain.label for domain in domains.list" id="domain_picker_select">
<option label="global" value="string:global" selected="selected">global</option>
<option label="TOP/Comm" value="string:6b16be7e6f72710f6">TOP/GBP/Comm</option>
<option label="TOP/Custom" value="string:e15e65256f9bd23">TOP/Custom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Both should work (but return different values). Note that the 1st one might be compacted: `$('#domain_picker_select option:selected').text();`.

Comment: ng-options. are you using angular??

Comment: I have tried $('#domain_picker_select option:selected').val(); but i am getting returned value as "undefined". may i know what might be the reason?

Comment: @Deep This is the code i got when i did the "inspect element" on my application form. The selectchoice is available on this form and i want the value of this selectchoice

Comment: could you show some more code?

Comment: @Deep PFB                                                                                                                  <select name="domain_picker_select" ng-options="domain.value as domain.label for domain in domains.list" id="domain_picker_select" ng-model="domains.currentValue" ng-change="updateDomain()" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"><option label="global" value="string:global" selected="selected">global</option>
</select>

Comment: @RishiReddy i meant not the  generated html in console. in your code if you are using angular , a model must be bind to the select and you can just use that scope variable

Comment: @RishiReddy are you using these codes with angularjs?

Comment: @Deep Unfortunately the code is been hidden with us, Could you please help me how to use the scope variable if the model is binded.

Comment: @jogesh_pi Might be because i do not know how is my application is been developed. If its build through angularjs then how would i get the value of selectechoice??

Comment: @RishiReddy selecting the element in angular is ```angular.element('select[name="name_of_element"]')```

Answer (score 1):

To get value, you use `val()`

```
$("#domain_picker_select").val();
```

It work good!
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBNxPo

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$("select#domain_picker_select").change(function(){
    var doma = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    console.log(doma); // output value to console
});
```

-

```
<select name="domain_picker_select"ng-options="domain.value as domain.label for domain in domains.list" id="domain_picker_select">
    <option label="global" value="string:global" selected>global</option>
    <option label="TOP/Comm" value="string:6b16be7e6f72710f6">TOP/GBP/Comm</option>
    <option label="TOP/Custom" value="string:e15e65256f9bd23">TOP/Custom</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to grab the selection on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document load
    var doma = $("select#domain_picker_select").find(":selected").text();
});
```

Comment: i think this would trigger when there is change in option, may i know how would i get the selected option on load. I mean i need the selected option value when form gets loaded.

Comment: sure! :-) one moment

Comment: I have tried your approach but it is still returning "empty" for my application. Does the reason for not getting the text  is "a model must be bind to the select and you can just use that scope variable " ?? Please help

Comment: @RishiReddy I have tested this on my end, and both functions work :/ I don't use Angular, so I wouldn't know what that means, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this way:

```
$("#domain_picker_select").on('change', function(){
    var doma = $(this).val();
    console.log(doma);
})
```

Hope this trick will help you.
Thank You :)

```js
$("#domain_picker_select").on('change', function(){
  var doma = $(this).val();
  console.log(doma);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<select name="domain_picker_select"ng-options="domain.value as domain.label for domain in domains.list" id="domain_picker_select">
<option label="global" value="string:global" selected="selected">global</option>
<option label="TOP/Comm" value="string:6b16be7e6f72710f6">TOP/GBP/Comm</option>
<option label="TOP/Custom" value="string:e15e65256f9bd23">TOP/Custom</option>
</select>
```